# Responsive site html/css

Tags: css, html

I have started to try to build a really easy website and trying to make it responsive. Something in the style of http://www.squarespace.com/ (Split up in different sections with different backgrounds etc that you just scroll throu) But i have a problem that I really cant figure out right now, I don't know how to make the foundation for this kind of site. I got the "menu" part quite nice, but as soon as I try to but some content on the first "part" or try to start the second part I run into trouble.

To try to explain I have two < p > that I tried to put on-top of the first part, and below to make the second part. I guess the explanation is not perfect, but hopefully the code can clear up my issue abit :)

Edit: Just took some random pictures to be able to show...

```css
#logo img{
  z-index: 10;
  left: 4%;
  top:20px;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
}

#signup img{
  z-index: 10;
  right: 4%;
  top:20px;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
}

#main-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height:308px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin:0;
}
#second-container { 

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="example.com">
                <img src="https://tcrf.net/images/d/de/FBEAR-nosave.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="signup">
      <a href="example.com">
        <img src="https://tcrf.net/images/d/de/FBEAR-nosave.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <div id="content">
    <div id="main-container">
      <img src="http://www.reallifeglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/background-radi-700x300.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <p>Ontop of background</p>
    <div id="second-container">
      <p>Under background</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gt2d6aa7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image in `main-container` is not set as a background image and it comes before the paragraphs in the source code, it is appearing on top of the paragraphs.

2 things you could do to get the paragraphs to show:

1) Set a position property on the paragraph style to make it appear on top of the image:

```
div.container p{position:relative;}
```

2) I would suggest setting that image as the background of your container and giving it a minimum height (in case your content does not increase the container size enough to fully see your image). Like so:

```
<div id="main-container" style="background-image:url('http://www.reallifeglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/background-radi-700x300.png');background-size:100%;min-height:300px;background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

Then, make sure to close your `main-container` before opening the `second-container`, that way it creates a clean section for different content. The way you have it, `second-container` is inside the `main-container` and any content that you wanted to appear below the main background and top content would actually just appear on top of the `main-container` background.

The Squarespace site you linked to is a good example visually, but if you inspect their code it gets a little confusing for a beginner, since they are nesting the bottom sections (below that video presentation) in a `section` within in a `div`.

Twitter Bootstrap has some good examples of one-page layouts with cleaner markup to follow. This is a good example: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-landing-page/

Here are their other examples: http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/one-page/

I am not an advocate of Bootstrap, since it adds a lot of unnecessary bloat in most cases, but these give a good indication of how to structure your page.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot to move on!